# Immediately published posts are scheduled and published 2 hours later

Tags: posts, scheduled-posts, timezones

If I try to publish posts immediately, they get scheduled for the current time but are published 2 hours later.

[image]

Also scheduled posts are published 2 hours after the planned time.

In think its a timezone issue but I've no clue where to look else:

Wordpress Setting:
[image]

PHP Setting:
[image]

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and the timezone seems to set there correct, too.

```
# timedatectl
  Local time: Sat 2016-10-01 18:04:13 CEST
  Universal time: Sat 2016-10-01 16:04:13 UTC
  RTC time: n/a
  Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CEST, +0200)
  Network time on: yes
  NTP synchronized: yes
  RTC in local TZ: no
```

mysql @@global.time_zone was set to SYSTEM, I tried to change it to UTC, but that doesn't fix the problem neither:

```
mysql> SET @@global.time_zone = '+00:00';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone;
+--------------------+
| @@global.time_zone |
+--------------------+
| +00:00             |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Do you have any hints where else I could look?

**Update1:**

I tried to populate timezones to mysql to set default time_zone to 'Europe/Berlin", but no luck:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -uroot mysql

mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Europe/Berlin';
mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone;
+--------------------+
| @@global.time_zone |
+--------------------+
| Europe/Berlin      |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Try scheduling the job 2 hours from Berlin time. See what happens.

Comment: If I schedule a post on a specific time, its published excatly 2 hours after that time.

Comment: Are your posts being moderated?

Comment: no, they aren't moderated

Comment: I'd suggest checking the time zone / time on your MySQL server / software. The post data will be put into the db first and then published. So if everything in your db is effectively written 2 hours from the actual time it's saved.

Comment: mysql @@global.time_zone was set to SYSTEM, I tried to change it to UTC, but that doesn't fix the problem neither

   select now();

 returns the local time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to

```
apt-get remove tzdata
apt-get install tzdata
```

while

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

was not enough.

Mark's edit:

In human words, the problem was caused because the time zone data on the server was incorrect, which probably had an impact how php calculates times. The solution was to forcefully update the data.

Comment: Editted to make it a little less technical. Feel free to edit my edit ;)